# Написать программу на C++ (при помощи циклов)

Tags: visual-c++

Вывести сумму квадратов чисел от 12 до 80.

Comment: `for(;;) { puts("173374"); break; }`

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.

Comment: Я пытался, не получается

Comment: А попытки где?...

Answer (score 2):

Ну что ж, с циклами, так с циклами...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

long long sum(int a, int b)
{
    long long v[3] = {b-a, b*b+a*a, b*b*b-a*a*a};
    long long c[3] = {1, 3, 2};

    long long Summa = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        Summa += v[i]*c[i];
    for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        Summa /= i;

    return Summa;
}

int main()
{
    cout << sum(12,80) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Скажите, можно ли long заменить другим циклом?

Comment: Конечно, можно :) Неужели вы не понимаете, что это в определенной мере стёб? Да, формально условия выполнены - есть циклы, сумма считается правильно. Вот только препод ждет от вас совсем-совсем другого. И я дал этот код в ответ на ваше учебное задание без попыток его решать именно потому, что хотя этот код и работает - вы все равно не сможете пояснить, как... Вам нужно начать работать самому - тогда вам помогут. Без этого - толку не будет...

Comment: Скажите, а вы учились на программиста?

Comment: А вы можете попытаться объяснить?)

Comment: @Harry ну ты тролль :) Написал бы просто цикл, в котором суммируются единицы столько раз какова сумма.

Comment: 1. Нет, специально не учился. По образованию скорее физик :) 2. Да, могу. Но, простите, не буду - я натянул цикл на готовую формулу суммы квадратов чисел от `a` до `b`.

Comment: @Zealint См. мой комментарий под исходным вопросом - чем не цикл? :)

Comment: @Harry, я видел, но там ясно, что смысла нет, потому что цикл не считает, а выводит, а в сумме единичек смысл есть - мы именно считаем в цикле.